# Push Notification defaulting to No Sounds and No Badge in iPhone Setup

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

In test and with a production "adhoc" build my remote push notifications are coming in with sound and a badge app icon.  When downloading the app from the store I am seeing a different behavior. I downloaded it to a phone running iOS 8.2 and I accepted remote notifications when the app launched.  However, checking the Notifications setup screen for my app in the iPhone's setting and I found the switch for "Sounds" and "Badge App Icon" were turned off.  Below is my code for setting these in the applications delegate.  What are the possible reasons these settings would have been turned off by default?

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                                         categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: Is this the first install of the app to that device? If not, were alerts turned off previously?

Comment: This was an update to an existing app.  In previous apps there were no notifications so nothing was set.

Comment: I'm going to speculate that somewhere along the way, a version (be it release or development) did the user notification registration and the disabled settings are carrying over. It's easy to test _if_ you have access to another 8.2 device that has never had the app installed.

Comment: I can say with 100% certainty that this device never had anything but the store version.  It was never used for any testing or adhoc builds.  I get what you are saying about getting another device and I am working on that.  Was just wondering if there was anyway those settings could be defaulted off based on the scenario I painted.

Comment: No way I'm aware of except a request being made that doesn't include the "off" pieces or residual "off" from a previous install.

Comment: Good to know.  Maybe this is some one-off weirdness.  Hope to confirm elsewhere.